# jquery ui datepicker deleting my text from input field

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a very simple html page with the following javascript in it

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );        
});
```

Then I have the input target element

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" class="boxtpl" name="${field.name}" value="${release?.startDate}">
```

and I see the html of the input from viewing source is valid...

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" class="boxtpl" name="release.startDate" value="2012-02-07">
```

so when I do the GET request to get this page, my date ONLY renders if I delete that last line in the javascript that sets the format WHICH is very important as that is the format I have playframework configured for!!!!!  If I don't set the format, the POST then breaks because formats don't match :(

Why is setting the format of datepicker clearing out my date????

I can try scripting more to set it manually though I tried calling the api to set it and that DID NOT work so it might not work doing raw javascript set either...not sure yet.  anyone know why this occurs or better yet how to fix it???

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug in jquery ui, but it seems that setting the format effectively deletes the default value. You can fix this with a chained

```
.datepicker("setDate", datepicker_default_val );
```

However, what I did in my web app was define a CSS class ".datepicker" then writing this code snippet provide date pickers to any with that class.

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).each( function(index){
          var datepicker_default_val = $(this).val();
          $( this ).datepicker({numberOfMonths: 3, showButtonPanel: true});
          $( this ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
          $( this ).datepicker("setDate", datepicker_default_val );
      });
```

What this does is grabs every element with the tagged class, saves the default value to local var **datepicker_default_val**, sets the formatting, and *then* restores the value.

Little bit of a hack but put that in a $(document).ready(function(){  }); block and you should be good.

Comment: Also you have to parse date `datepicker_default_val = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $(this).val())`.

Answer (score 2):

If the input field does not match the default dateFormat, it will simply delete it.
The option setting in the second line is too late then, after the first line it is already deleted.

Solution: Set the dateFormat in the first call:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by:

> the POST then breaks because formats don't match

Also, I don't quite understand what you mean by your GET and POST requests? Do you mean the form methods? In such case you should amend your HTML code with the surrounding form tags and add a submit button so we can understand exactly what you want and try to reproduce the problem.

Anyway, see if this is what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/DAMEj/

Actually I just included the Jquery UI library in addition to their CSS for a full test of your code.

Besides, I don't get the purpose of these attributes `name="${field.name}" value="${release?.startDate}"`, could you clarify?

And finally, what is it exactly that doesn't work for you?

EDIT:

So according to my last comment about the default date display, please check this out http://jsfiddle.net/sidou/ZUrPj/ and see if it fits your needs.

Happy JS fiddling ;)

Comment: Change the html to the what the browser received which as I said was <input id="datepicker" type="text" class="boxtpl" name="somefield" value="2012-02-17">​ and that AWESOME tool you showed me demonstrates it(just delete the one line of javascript and it works again).  +1 just for that cool tool you showed me.

Comment: this tool is toooo cool.  Basically, this http://jsfiddle.net/b5qaP/ does not work, while this does http://jsfiddle.net/x7jfz/

Comment: I think I start to understand what you want! We are talking about a default date value that must be displayed in the input field at the beginning right?

Comment: yes, I just resolved it as I found out you can pass dateformat into the constructor instead and that works fine. but can't change it afterwords without deleting the data :( which seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

If the input value is not parseable by jQuery, it will indeed delete the value from the input field (and even from the altField, if you set one).

For example, this might happen when using different locales. If you set the datepicker dateFormat to 'dd MM yy' and use French localisation, it will parse "10 Mars 2012", however a value of "10 March 2012" will get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i found than the JQuery was inyected by a "formoid" solution, soo, i just replace the function where the data was reinjected, adding the line

> "value": date.attr("value")

I mixed with the [Shaun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884903/1224162) answer too:

```
jQuery(".formoid-flat-blue").find('input[type=date]').each(function(){
    var date = $(this);
    var datepicker_default_val = $(this).val();
    var text = $('<input type="text">');
    text.get(0).className = date.get(0).className;
    text.attr({
        "name": date.attr("name"),
        "placeholder": date.attr("placeholder"),
        "required": date.attr("required"),
        "value": date.attr("value")
    });
    date.replaceWith(text);
    text.datepicker({
        format:  _dateFormat || date.attr("data-format") || 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    if (datepicker_default_val) {
        text.datepicker({
            setDate:  datepicker_default_val
        });
    }
});
```